# Why a String drawn on a Graphics object change its position depending on the used skin?

Tags: drawing, codenameone

If I draw a String onto a Graphics (from a mutable image) in a specific position why does the String position moves (on the Y Axis) depending on the simulator skin that is used ?

```
public void paints(Graphics g, Image background, Image watermark, int width, int height) {

g.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
g.drawImage(watermark, 0, 0);
g.setColor(0xFF0000);

// Upper left corner
g.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);

// Lower right corner
g.setColor(0x00FF00);
g.fillRect(width - 10, height - 10, 10, 10);

g.setColor(0xFF0000);
Font f = Font.createTrueTypeFont("Geometos", "Geometos.ttf").derive(220, Font.STYLE_BOLD);
g.setFont(f);
// Draw a string right below the M from Mercedes on the car windscreen (measured in Gimp)
g.drawString("HelloWorld", 
        (int) (848 ),
        (int) (610)
        );

}
```

This is the way I save a screenshot programatically with CodenameOne :

```
    Image screenshot = Image.createImage(photoBase.getWidth(), photoBase.getHeight());
    f.revalidate();
    f.setVisible(true);
    drawing.paintComponent(screenshot.getGraphics(), true);

    String imageFile = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "screenshot.png";
    try(OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(imageFile)) {
        ImageIO.getImageIO().save(screenshot, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, 1);
    } catch(IOException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here is the result with the iPhone 6 skin :
[image: iPhone 6Screenshot]

And with the Xoom skin :
[image: Xoom Screenshot]

Thanks a lot to anyone that could give me hints on how to solve this problem and start the String always at the position nevermind the skin (and device) used !

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Is the "drawing" component on the screen?

If so it will be sized differently based on the specific device you are running on as each device has different densities/resolutions. So elements from the screen will appear in different positions which is what we want normally.

Comment: Thanks @Shai! The drawing component is indeed on the screen 

`f.setLayout(new LayeredLayout());
  final Label drawing = new Label();
  f.addComponent(drawing);`

Should I add my drawing component to another form that is not on the screen and then save (screenshot) this other form so that the string does not move ?

Comment: I don't get your point. In my paints method I used width and height from the Mercedes car photo (they are the same dimensions than the one I get with Gimp). I also draw a rectangle in the bottom right corner at width ; height. The green point is exactly where I expect it to be. 

Furthermore I know the M from Mercedes on the windscreen is located at (848 ; 610). So why does the upper left corner of my Hello World string does not start here ? Do you mean it is normal behaviour ? Then what the use of passing position arguments to the drawString() ;-) ? Cheers

Comment: There is a big piece missing between paints and `paintComponent` which I'm assuming calls everything on the paint() callback. I suggest that instead of using `paintComponent` you call `paints` directly from your image rendering code and thus avoid potential translate issues.

Comment: But if I draw the String at (0;0) its upper left corner starts at (0;0) without translation (so no offset). But if I draw the same String at (X;Y) its upper left corner starts somewhere WHEREAS fillRect(X,Y, 10, 10) draws a rectangle starting exactly at (X;Y). And I do use my method outside the paint method. I'll start a new question on that specific point so that I can illustrate it with pictures.

Comment: Problem solved by upgrading project libs from version 114 to version 115  ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986722/why-do-i-get-a-different-behviour-in-codename-one-simulator-than-on-a-real-andro for details). It was a simulator only issue indeed!